# Best practice to change component based on URL params in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Just curious, for a route like `/chart/:charttype`

I want to load different type of chart components into that chart area, **how to plan this** in VueRouter(currently I only put `/chart/:charttype` there) and component( currently I put a container component there, inside which, there is a long list of `v-if` different type of chart components )? Any best practice?

```
/*
    Say I have a long list of diff type of charts, 
    when charttype matches, it will load that component, 
    otherwise load 404 component there. 
*/


 _______________________
 |    _____________    |
 |    |           |    |
 |    |   chart   |    |
 |    |___________|    |
 |_____________________|
```

I believe current long list of `v-if` way will be very hard for maintenance, also, in the future, that chart area will be a  a group of charts which build a combo chart component(such as 4 charts as a combo chart component), so I guess there has to be a configurable way to do this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) in the docs

```
<component :is="componentName"></component>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. BTW, like I mentioned, since that component name needs to be passed from URL param,  how to handle invalid component name that I need to pass in 404Error component?

Comment: I guess you could put accepted component name array `acceptedComponent` then check if it is in the array load it, else load 404 component, if you wish me to write a small example for you I will be happy to do it

Comment: thanks, so there has to be a manually maintained component list? Also, how to pass in props to <component>?

Comment: Ok I found a way to search in global available components, if it exists it will show it else it will show the error, here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wguyjgeq/3/) ,  it might not be the desired behavior. I believe it is not the best way

Comment: so for that $options.components, where did U specify components attribution? Is it auto registered after Vue find all components to load?

Comment: So I read [this post in Vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/list-registered-vue-components/7556) , I am not sure if it register every component available. [Vue options in the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options)